# IBus: Couldn't receive data from agent

Tags: emacs23

I load ibus in Emacs, but I active ibus fail.
The note is IBus: Couldn't receive data from agent.
Thank

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to set up `LC_CTYPE`. As I used Chinese input with ibus, I just set `LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8` . Without such setting, it seems not possible to trigger ibus-mode properly.